# How to add a link two report in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following tables (and their structures).

```
airplane (airplane_id,type,total_seats,start A ,end A,start B,end B,startC,endC)

flight_schedule (flight_id,departure_dt,source,destination,arrival_dt)
               pk10     1-12-15      pew      kar       2-12-15

flight_seating_detail (flight_id,departure_dt,seat_no,class,fare,status)
```

I have created a form and reports on these two tables, and I want to add a link to `flight_id`, when click on that I want to start filling in `flight_seating_detail` table as `(pk10, 1-12-15, 1, 'a', 20000, open)` up to limited rows with a change in `seat_no`.

I have a code for this but how can I use this in apex column link. Please do help me!

Answer (score 0):

are you running apex 5 or 4?
on apex 5, under the report that has been created find the column you wanted to link, there is a link property that lets you set the target page together with what value you want to pass in order for you to fetch the data you wanted to show